# How to call a function in a list of functions in python

Tags: python, pyside2

I want to make a financial calculator by using GUI, which can calculate some basic calculation functions.
Currently my program has main two functions `future_value` and `present_value`.
But when I calculate, it will call my previous function and print out the result on the terminal. For example, my previous function is `future_value`, and now there is a new function called `present_value`. When I press the calculation button, It will also call `future_value` in the terminal and print it out.
But I only want `present_value` to be called.

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class COMPOUND_INTEREST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = QUiLoader().load("bb\IA compound  designer.ui")
        self.ui.setWindowTitle("Compound interest")
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.future_value)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.present_value)

    def future_value(self):
        N = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
        I = float(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text())
        PV = float(self.ui.lineEdit_3.text())
        C_Y = int(self.ui.lineEdit_7.text())
        jb = (1 + (I / (100 * C_Y))) ** N
        res = abs(jb * PV)
        print(res)
        self.ui.lineEdit_6.setText(str(round(res, 2)))

    def present_value(self):
        F_V = float(self.ui.lineEdit_6.text())
        N = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
        I = float(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text())
        C_Y = int(self.ui.lineEdit_7.text())
        x = (1 + (I / (100 * C_Y))) ** N
        res = -abs(F_V / x)
        print(res)
        self.ui.lineEdit_3.setText(str(round(res, 2)))


app = QApplication([])
COMPOUND_INTEREST = COMPOUND_INTEREST()
COMPOUND_INTEREST.ui.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: No images. Post all texts as text

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Show only the relevant code, and if possible create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also `future_value` does not exists in your post.

Comment: Well, you *did* `connect` both functions to the button...

Comment: how should I do that??

Comment: I would recommend using better names for your controls. One day soon you're going to forget what all the `lineEdit_X` strings are supposed to represent.

Comment: okok,I will fix that

Comment: At present, I want to click the calculate button and calculate the result, but the two functions seem to be wrapped together, and I want to separate them.

Comment: What do you believe the `self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect` calls do?

Comment: it will connect with the function I have, so there is a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you `.connect`, you're adding another slot to this signal. You can disconnect all the added slots like so:

```py
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.diconnect()
```

... or you could disconnect one specific slot by passing it as a parameter:

```py
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.disconnect(self.future_value)
```

Put all together, this would make your constructor look like so:

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.ui = QUiLoader().load("bb\IA compound  designer.ui")
    self.ui.setWindowTitle("Compound interest")
    # Connect a slot
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.future_value)
    # Connect a new slot
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.present_value)
    # Disconnect the first slot
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.disconnect(self.future_value)
```

Comment: really really appriciate!!!!!

Comment: but it seems that if I disconnect, then it won't show me the result.....

Comment: @pythonlearner I'm confused. Which function do you want to run?

Comment: ,now the calculation button has two functions, one is to calculate PV and the other is to calculate FV. But now I want a function, which is not to print the result of PV on the terminal when I calculate FV, and not to print the result of FV on the terminal when I calculate PV. I tried your method, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @pythonlearner how do you determine which one (FV/PV) you want to calculate? You only have 1 button.

Comment: ,So I want to set it as universal button,so it can calculate both those two, the only differences is the formula, and the blank I leave. if I level FV as blank, and other parameter are filled, then computer knows I want to calculte FV, vice versa;

Comment: @pythonlearner then I think you should make the button point to a new function which does that if statement. `self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check_if_do_FV_or_PV)`, then in that function you check whether FV/PV is blank, and then you run the other funciton.